# find the limit of $a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{(n+3)^{n+1}}(\sqrt{n^{2}+3}-n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

can someone help me find the limit of $a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{(n+3)^{n+1}}(\sqrt{n^{2}+3}-n)$ and explain too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt[n]{(n+3)^{n+1}}(\sqrt{n^{2}+3}-n)=\frac{3(n+3)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{n+\sqrt{n^2+3}}=$$
$$=\frac{3(n+3)\sqrt[n]{n+3}}{n+\sqrt{n^2+3}}=\frac{3(1+\frac{3}{n})}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}}\cdot\sqrt[n]{n+3}\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

First write
$$
\sqrt[n]{(n+3)^{n+1}}=(n+3)\sqrt[n]{n+3}
$$
Now,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(\sqrt[n]{n+3})=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+3)}{n}=0
$$
which implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+3}=1$. Thus you just need to find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+3)(\sqrt{n^2+3}-n)
$$
If the limit of the corresponding function exists, then it's the same as the limit of the sequence; you can also apply the substitution $x=1/t$:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1+3t}{t}\frac{\sqrt{1+3t^2}-1}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(1+3t)(1+3t^2/2+o(t^2)-1)}{t^2}
$$